# Images aren't displayed in listbox after binding

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I am having an issue where in a listbox binding text is being displayed but none of the binding images are. I download and parse an xml file just fine and display the text I want but then want to show an image depending on the status. `Linename` and `Service` show OK but the binding image does not show at all. Atype is just used to call the GetImage method (not neat I know). It should then set the ImageSource according to the status but no image is shown at all.

```
 XElement XmlTweet = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
 var ns = XmlTweet.GetDefaultNamespace();

 listBox1.ItemsSource = from tweet in XmlTweet.Descendants(ns + "LineStatus")
                                   select new FlickrData
   {

 Linename = tweet.Element(ns + "Line").Attribute("Name").Value,                                     
 Service = tweet.Element(ns + "Status").Attribute("Description").Value,
 Atype = GetImage(tweet.Element(ns + "Status").Attribute("Description").Value)

    };


     public String GetImage(String type)
    {
      FlickrData f = new FlickrData();
        switch(type)
    {

        case "Good Service":
            f.Type = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/status_good.png", UriKind.Relative));
            break;
        case "Minor Delays":
            f.Type = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/status_minor.png", UriKind.Relative));
            break;
        case "Severe Delays":
            f.Type = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/status_severe.png", UriKind.Relative));
            break;
        case "Planned Closure":
            f.Type = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/status_minor.png", UriKind.Relative));
            break;
       }
      return "anything";
    }
```

In FlickrData it is a simple get set with the imagesource `Type` not displaying.

```
 public class FlickrData


    {
        public string Linename { get; set; }
        public string Service { get; set; }
        public string Detail { get; set; }
        public ImageSource Type { get; set; }
        public string Atype { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: How are you setting up the bindings in the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converters come into handy in such situations.

First, your image in the XAML should be defined like this

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=Atype, Converter={StaticResource AtypeToImageConverter}}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

Then create a converter class in the project. (Right click on project name -> select Add -> select Class )

Name the class as "AtypeToImageConverter"

```
public class AtypeToImageConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(ImageSource))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be an ImageSource");

        BitmapImage result = null;
        int type = value.ToString();

        switch (type)
        {
            case "Good Service":
                result = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/status_good.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;

            case "Minor Delays":
                result = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/status_minor.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;

            //other cases
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

}
```

and it will do the magic. You can remove the Type from your FlickrData class.
Any doubt, just google on how to use converters in C#

Comment: Many thanks for the help. Got it working. It should also be noted to add the following in the XAML as well.
`xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Mynamespace"`
`<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <c:AtypeToImageConverter x:Key="AtypeToImageConverter"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>`